# "fatal error: Python.h: No Such File or Directory" when compiling python file to a c executable file?

Tags: python3

I am trying to compile `c` from `python`.

There shows the following errors after I executing the following commands:

```
-Wall -I/usr/include/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a -lpython35 -o prime_numbers_2 prime_numbers_2.c

prime_numbers_2.c:11:20: fatal error: Python.h: No Such File or
directory compilation terminated.
```

I also search in the directory `/usr/lib` with the following command:

```
find . -name Python.h
```

but there is no `Python.h` in that directory.

How can I fix these problems? Should I reinstall Python3.5.2?

Answer (score 16):

You should install the development package of Python which contains header files and the library of Python.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Sources:

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-python-h-file-not-found-error-solution/
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python3-dev

Comment: I remove and reinstall python3-dev and check the compile links, there still shows some errors below.

Comment: paultsai@paultsai-virtual-machine:~/cython/ex2$ gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/python3.5/ -lpython3.5 -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/  -o prime_numbers_2 prime_numbers_2.c

Comment: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: in function _start: (.text+0x20): undefined reference to「main」 /tmp/ccgBhADM.o: in function __Pyx_PyObject_GetAttrStr: prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to「PyObject_GetAttr」 /tmp/ccgBhADM.o: in function __pyx_pf_15prime_numbers_2_is_prime: prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to「PyTuple_New」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x24b): undefined reference to「PyList_Type」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x267): undefined reference to「PyTuple_Type」

Comment: There can be a problem with locations of the files mentioned in `-l` and `-L` options. Check if they exist and that `-l` points to a regular file and `-L` to a directory.

Answer (score 0):

For those people who came here and are using pypy, make sure to do:

```
sudo apt-get install pypy3-dev
```